# Is there any Swagger for coinbase-api?

Tags: coinbase-api

I was looking in https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#introduction to see if there is any Swagger file for Coinbase API but did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found an unofficial one:

https://github.com/CoinFabrik/coinbase-api-swagger

I've no idea how accurate and/or up-to-date it is.